# using dispatch is returning Actions must be plain objects

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using Redux and call a async function using connect store.

Here is my view file code `recordings.js` where I write the below code:

```
fetchREcordingJson(file_name) {

  const {
    dispatch,
    history
  } = this.props;


  dispatch(fetchRecordingJson(file_name))

  console.log(dispatch(fetchRecordingJson(file_name)));

}

const mapStateToProps = ({
  recordings
}) => {
  return {
    recordings

  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
    ...bindActionCreators({
      getRecordingsList,
      getRecordingsListById,
      getRecordingsListByUserId,
      getRecordingsSearchList,
      getRecordingsSearchListListByUserId,
      getRecordedListWithOrder,
      getRecordedListWithOrderbyClient,
      getRecordedListWithOrderbyUserId,
      getRecordingsTags,
      fetchRecordingJson,
    }, dispatch)
  }
}


export default injectIntl(

  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(RecordingsPage))

);
```

And below is my redux `action.js` code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import FileDownload from 'react-file-download';

import {
  RECEIVE_JSON,
}
from '../actions';

export function receiveJSON(json, file_name) {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_JSON,
    file_name,
    data: json
  }
}

export function fetchRecordingJson(file_name) {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get(API_URL + `fetchjson/${file_name}`)
      .then(json => {
        dispatch(receiveJSON(json.data, file_name))
      })

  }
}
```

And `reducer.js` code:

```
const INIT_STATE = {
  info: {},
  data: [],
  count: 0,
  annotations: [
    []
  ]

};

case RECEIVE_JSON:
  let newState = {
    data: action.data.data,
    info: action.data.info,
    count: state.count
  };
newState.annotations = action.data.annotations.length === 0 ? [
  []
] : action.data.annotations || [
  []
];
newState.file_name = action.file_name;
return Object.assign({}, newState);
```

Either I use `this.props.fetchRecordingJson(file_name)`
or  `dispatch(fetchRecordingJson(file_name))` it returns the same error

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

I am strugling from much time to resolve this but could not get success can anyone who worked on async calls using redux and dispatch can tell what would be the reason and how to resolve this

thanks

Comment: Well, the action creator `fetchRecordingJson` returns a function. That isn't a plain object. Have you correctly configured your middleware? What asynchronous action library are you using, redux-thunk?

Comment: As the message clearly states, you need to use custom middleware such as `redux-thunk` if you want to do asynchronous stuff in your actions

Comment: well I am not using any library

Comment: thank you guys using redux-thunk resolve my issue. thank you so much for your guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, a Redux store doesn't know anything about async logic. You need to use middleware in order to make it work. It's easy. For instance, to add `redux-thunk` you need only:

```
// install: npm install redux-thunk

// configure your store
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '<path to your root reducer>';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

And that's basically it.

These docs are worth to look at:

- [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)
- [Redux: Using Middleware to Enable Async Logic](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#using-middleware-to-enable-async-logic)

Answer (score 0):

Action on redux always must return an object. If you wanna implement asynchronous, you must use middleware to custom such as redux-thunk, redux-saga, observable...etc